# how create document Object into HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a `document` Object into HTML page using javaScript
to execute a new HTML page into it;
like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ... some head tags appened
    <script>
       // not problem of with jquery or not
      function createDocument(){
        var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
        var targetElement = document.getElementById('targetElement')
        // so i need to know how can use [ta.value]
        // to execute it in new DOCUMENT Element appended it in [targetElement]
        // without get or set global variables in origin document
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="ta"></textarea>
    <div id="targetElement">
      <!-- need to append new html document HERE! -->
    </div>
    <!-- 
         when click the run Button the value of text area can be 
         running content to create new document object into targetElement
     -->
    <button onclick="createDocument()">RUN</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `createElementById`? Are you really mixing `createElement` with `getElementById`?

Comment: try something like `var ta=(document.createElement("div")).setAttribute("id","ta");`

Comment: ops sorry yeah, i mean `getElementById` yeah

Comment: my problem, not with elements, it's How to create new Document Object content A value of text area ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably mixed up `.getElementById` and `.createElement`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function createDocument(){
        var ta = document.getElementById('ta').value;
        var targetElement = document.getElementById('targetElement');
        targetElement.innerHTML = eval(ta);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea onchange="createDocument();" id="ta"></textarea>
    <div id="targetElement">
      <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this way keep the global variables to use if I'm using in `<textarea>` new script

Comment: @imel changing my answer to (probably) reflect your question. adding `onchange` and change `targetElement.innerHTML = "blablabla"` into `targetElement.innerHTML = ta`

Comment: I need to execute new HTML code, in your example isn't create new Document Object, if I want to write new script in `textarea` it's can't be executing, and that's my problem. thanks,

Comment: @imel ah i misunderstood your question, just change `targetElement.innerHTML = ta;` into `targetElement.innerHTML = eval(ta);`